# Java: A Thread don't modify the GUI even with SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, invokelater

I have a problem with this code:

```
public class Gui_01 extends JFrame {

private JPanel display;
private ActionListener visualizza() {
    ActionListener evento = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            display.removeAll();

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    JPanel visualizza = new JPanel();
                    visualizza.add(new JLabel("Test", SwingConstants.CENTER));

                    display.add(visualizza, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                    updateProgress(visualizza);
                }
            }
            );

            t.start();
        }
    };
    return evento;
}

private void updateProgress(final JPanel visualizza) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            display.add(visualizza, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
    });
}}
```

I don't understand why the code don't work properly, the thread t and the thread in updateProgress work fine, but any modification to display won't affect the GUI even with invokeLater.

```
display.add(visualizza, BorderLayout.SOUTH)
```

This code don't modify the gui, i know it's normal (due to Swing), but why invokeLater don't work.

Sorry for my bad english, thanks in advance for replys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get rid of the `display.add(visualizza, BorderLayout.SOUTH);` statement in your thread. as you should never update or modify the UI from outside the context of the EDT...

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        JPanel visualizza = new JPanel();
        visualizza.add(new JLabel("Test", SwingConstants.CENTER));

        //display.add(visualizza, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        updateProgress(visualizza);
    }
}
```

In fact, I'd discourage your from creating UI elements outside of the EDT, as you can't guarantee when they might start interacting with the UI.

Second, call `revalidate` and `repaint` after you've updated the UI...

```
private void updateProgress(final JPanel visualizza) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            display.add(visualizza, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            display.revalidate();
            display.repaint();
        }
    });
}}
```

Swing is lazy when it comes to updating the UI, this is a good thing, as it allows you to make sweeping changes and only update the UI when you're ready to do so.

I'd also encourage you to use a `SwingWorker` instead, as it has functionality which you can use to synchronise the updates with the EDT.  See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Glad it could help